# JBOSS server log showing error SESSIONINFO adding null values

Tags: java, jboss, drools, jbpm

I have war file which is deployed in **jboss-eap-6.3**, JBPM is runnning on **jboss-eap-6.4**.We are using decision tables(excel sheets) which are handled in **JBPM**.
We are using RESTful webserive with ejb and java.
And for executing the rules we are using **drools-6.0.1.Final**.
Whenever i have a small request for about 4-5 values it gives output.
But whenever i have a response of about more than 100 values i get this error in server.log file of jboss-eap-6.4:

> 18:45:09,146 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]
>   (EJB default - 141) SQL Error: 50200, SQLState: HYT00 18:45:09,147
>   WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default
>   - 138) SQL Error: 50200, SQLState: HYT00 18:45:09,163 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 141)
>   Timeout trying to lock table "SESSIONINFO"; SQL statement: insert into
>   SessionInfo (id, lastModificationDate, rulesByteArray, startDate,
>   OPTLOCK) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?) [50200-168] 18:45:09,168 ERROR
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 138)
>   Timeout trying to lock table "SESSIONINFO"; SQL statement: insert into
>   SessionInfo (id, lastModificationDate, rulesByteArray, startDate,
>   OPTLOCK) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?) [50200-168] 18:45:09,164 WARN 
>   [org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService] (EJB default -
>   141) Could not commit session:
>   javax.persistence.PessimisticLockException: could not execute
>   statement     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapLockException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1459)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1344)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:881)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
>     at
>   org.drools.persistence.jpa.JpaPersistenceContext.persist(JpaPersistenceContext.java:56)
>   [drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
>     at
>   org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.(SingleSessionCommandService.java:110)
>   [drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor253.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) [:1.8.0_144]  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]    at
>   org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.buildCommandService(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:171)
>   [drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
>     at
>   org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.newKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:70)
>   [drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
>     at
>   org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.newKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:39)
>   [drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
>     at
>   org.kie.internal.persistence.jpa.JPAKnowledgeService.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(JPAKnowledgeService.java:121)
>   [kie-internal-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.factory.JPASessionFactory.newKieSession(JPASessionFactory.java:42)
>   [jbpm-runtime-manager-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
>     at
>   org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.PerRequestRuntimeManager$PerRequestInitializer.initKieSession(PerRequestRuntimeManager.java:203)
>   [jbpm-runtime-manager-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
>     at
>   org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeEngineImpl.getKieSession(RuntimeEngineImpl.java:70)
>   [jbpm-runtime-manager-6.5.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:6.5.0.Final-redhat-2]
>     at myproject.execute(myejbclass.java:28) [oneofmyejb.jar:]  at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor210.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [:1.8.0_144]  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:86)
>   [jboss-as-weld-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:97)
>   [jboss-as-weld-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
>   [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:93)
>   [jboss-as-weld-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:280)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:345)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:243)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:79)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>   [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:332)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$100(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:69)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:202)
>   [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]    at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.PessimisticLockException: could not execute statement
>     at org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect$2.convert(H2Dialect.java:314)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:189)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2987)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3499)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:395)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:229)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:209)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:193)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:772)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:746)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:750)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:875)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
>     ... 73 more Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Timeout trying
>   to lock table "SESSIONINFO"; SQL statement: insert into SessionInfo
>   (id, lastModificationDate, rulesByteArray, startDate, OPTLOCK) values
>   (null, ?, ?, ?, ?) [50200-168]    at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
>     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)  at
>   org.h2.table.RegularTable.doLock(RegularTable.java:500)   at
>   org.h2.table.RegularTable.lock(RegularTable.java:434)     at
>   org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:123)     at
>   org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:84)  at
>   org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:75)  at
>   org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:230)    at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:156)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:142)
>     at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:186)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]  ...
>   94 more

I am trying to find a solution on the internet but i have got no success. I tried to change the timeout time,increase the thread-pool size, increased the threads size everywhere in standalone.xml.If someone can give me a idea or point me to some related articles to this that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using the JBPM, somewhere h2 database was configured as a datasource in our application (standalone.xml), so when many requests came at once, the h2 database could not handle it and gave **pessimisticlockexception**

> The solution was to add **MVCC=true** in the url which is mutliversion
>   concurrency control and you can [read more](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#mvcc) about it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to H2 DB and not directly with JBoss per se.

Exception:

```
18:45:09,146 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 141) SQL Error: 50200, SQLState: HYT00 18:45:09,147 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 138) SQL Error: 50200, SQLState: HYT00 18:45:09,163 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 141)
```

As described in Social [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2387da0c-726a-495c-b2d2-0b32891aea52/sqlstate-hyt00-login-timeout-expired-a-networkrelated-or-instancespecific-error-has-occurred?forum=sqlgetstarted), the issue might be related to the SQL Server mixed authentication mode or to the DNS communication.

But particularly on your case, the lines below show that the statement couldn't be committed to the table "SESSIONINFO", thus  it's throwing a time out exception:

```
Could not commit session: javax.persistence.PessimisticLockException: could not execute statement at
```